# What's the meaning of: 'request => out => ' in Play Framework

Tags: scala, syntax, playframework

While I was diving in the Play Framework 2 reference documentation, I foun this syntax regarding WebSockets:

```
def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>
  MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
}
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets

But I'm not able to understand the "meaning" of this syntax 'request => out'. I can infer that from a WebSocket request, I get an ActorRef called *out*, but I'm asking if anyone can make me see the match with this syntax and the method signature found in their [API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.WebSocket$).

I've used Akka+Scala to develop a small application so I know some scala basic syntax.

**Solved**

See both Angelo Genovese and bjfletcher answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request ⇒ out ⇒ MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
```

Is a function which takes a `RequestHeader` and returns a function which takes an `ActorRef` and returns a `Props`

in the API you linked this is represented as

```
f: (RequestHeader) ⇒ (ActorRef) ⇒ Props
```

it might be easier to visualize this way:

```
def first(request: RequestHeader) = {
  def second (out: ActorRef) = {
    MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
  }
  second _
}
```

Comment: But what's happening when I'm doing 'request => out'? I mean, request and out have not been declared anywhere, so... I'm defining the function in-place? I'm trying to match this syntax with the ones used in, for example: numberList.foreach { number => println(number) } but I'm not sure I'm right...

Comment: You're not doing `request => out` you're doing `request => { out => ... }`

Comment: @Daenyth modified the code with the '{ }', it works too (as you would expect), so the first syntax is a syntactic sugar then?

Comment: @vicaba More or less. It's not quite sugar, it's a facet of the fact that everything is an expression. `{ ... }` is an expression that results the last evaluated return value of whatever is inside the braces. You can omit them (generally) when the inside is a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the definition for `acceptWithActor`:

```
def acceptWithActor(f: RequestHeader => HandlerProps)
```

you see that it takes in a parameter that is a function, which takes in a `RequestHeader` object and produces a `HandlerProps` object.

Your goal therefore is to put together a function that takes `RequestHeader`:

```
request => { ... produce HandlerProps here ... }
```

now, you need to return a `HandlerProps` object, let's have a look at what this is:

```
type HandlerProps = ActorRef => Props
```

so, your next goal is to take in an `ActorRef` object and produce a `Props`:

```
request => {
    actorRef => {
        ... produce Props here ...
    }
}
```

now, you need to produce a `Props` object:

```
MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
```

Putting it all together, you have your code there.  Play uses the convention of naming the actor reference as `out` not `actorRef`.

I hope this helps.

#### Update (see comments)

You can indeed specify the types:

```
....acceptWithActor[String, String] { request: RequestHeader => out: ActorRef => ...
```

which sometimes can read better than without.  They're not necessary because they're indeed inferred by the compiler which looks at all this in the same way as I explained above.

Comment: Yep, it is more clear now. But I still don't understand why 'request' is of type RequestHeader and 'out' is of type ActorRef if I'm not specifying it anywhere or is it inferred by the compiler?

Comment: You can absolutely add the type to request. See edited answer.

Comment: It's inferred then, thank you! Sorry that I can mark two correct answers, but I'll update my question to clarify that both answers are meaningful.